# How to track a user time between login and logout activity i.e. to track that how much time he/she spend between login and logout

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am working on a task. To build a middleware using Django rest framework that can track the user time from the moment he/she logins and do some activity and then logout. I have to track the time he/she spends between login and logout using middleware. Please suggest some proper procedures to complete the task. I am new to django and restframework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to set a variable to `time.time()` when they log in, and set another variable to `time.time()` when they log out. Then subtract the values to get the number of seconds.

```
def login ():
  login_time = time.time()

def logout ():
  logout_time = time.time()

#To get the number of seconds the user spent on the platform,
#subtract login_time from logout_time
```

Comment: I had to use middle-ware. where should i define login_time = time.time()?

Comment: @Cartucho can you give me the answer to the question, please?

Comment: @RazaUllah, Do it in the code that is run when the user logs in, then make sure the variable is accessible to the code ran when they log out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no database is involved in saving the login time value, you would need a cache utility to store username -> login time information to be able to correctly calculate the time spent in a session. To accomplish this with Django Middleware, you can rely on [process_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) method. If the view is a login view, log in the user and create a cache entry of login time against the username/email. Similarly, when the user logs out, find the cache entry for that user, calculate the active time, and remove the entry from the cache. You can also use some global dict/variable to store time values but that is not a viable solution in the long run.